# What are the pins on the rear end of a RTX 2080 Super GPU for?

Tags: gpu, power

I just saw some unused pins on the rear end of my GPU and was wondering what they were and what they are normally used for.

I don't know if any other type of GPUs have these leftover pins.

[image: Rear end GPU pins]

There seems to be some connector going to the fans using the same type of pins.

Could I use these unused pins to power more fans or more rgb lights strips?

**Edit**
Here's closeup pictures of the same pins in my PC. (Sorry for the dusty GPU)
[image: GPU side pins 1]
[image: PGU side pins 2]

Comment: It's impossible to say without taking the cover plate off but they are not "leftover pins"

Comment: No, they're in the wrong place for that. They're likely used to run checks on the GPU during the manufacturing process.

Comment: @acejavelin You can see the SLI connector at the other end of the picture (Top-Left) and the PCIe connector on the opposite side of the card (Top-Right)

Comment: @Ramhound Do you think these connectors have a label under the white plate?

Comment: @spikey_richie Do you have any sources to believe that is the case?

Comment: Experience. I've worked in manufacturing environments where PCB's had headers for diagnostic work, or to allow the programming of an EPLD. There's no value in removing the header.

Comment: "Do you think these connectors have a label under the white plate?" The copper plane will have some text etched in, but it won't say "this plug is for more RGB!". It'll say something like `ext_int_1` or something meaningless to most people.

Comment: @acejavelin - The SLI pins are on the top of the GPU.  Those pins would be on the side of the GPU.

Comment: @LoukMouk - Based on the screenshots you have provided it's impossible for us to say one way or another.  It's very unlikely those pins are a FAN/RGB header consider the number of pins there appears to be.

Comment: The user manual makes no mention of the connector, so it must be for manufacturing use>>>>https://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/GEFORCE_RTX_2080_SUPER_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: @Moab I looked at this exact document before posting my question! (: But saw nothing about these pins. That's why I asked.

Comment: Like we said it is for manufacturing purposes, not for the end user.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I am aware they normally are, but the original picture the OP had made it look like it was an edge connector there, so I tried to make an educated guess. The new pictures clearly show that is not the case.